# Razor Umbraco 7 CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue Serialize issue

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

i am using an for each but its not iterating properly instead its displaying a characters i think its Conversion issue can any one help me on this.

the array returing is CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("promo")

```
[ { "alias": "1", "content": "1", "img": "/media/1069/509253678.jpg" }, { "alias": "Slide 2", "content": "2", "img": "/media/1074/636609180.jpg" } ]
```

the code is

```
 @{

    if (CurrentPage.HasValue("promo"))
    {
        var promoListValue = CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("promo");  
     foreach (var item in promoListValue)
            {
                <span>@item </span>
            }
    }   

}
```

but its displaying like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: What kind of property are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: Is it a content picker? If yes, you should probably use `CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("promo")` or something like that

Comment: its a custom property i am created , the response picture i have attached above

Comment: you should write a value converter for it (you are getting the string and looping through the characters. take a look at https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developing-packages/78995-custom-property-value-converter for example

Comment: i can able to access only using CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("promo") but not wit this Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<MyLookAlikeArchetypeModel>("promo") @Eyescream

Comment: You have to write some code to make it work (take a look at the last post in the thread i linked before)

Comment: yeah in the post they are using Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<MyLookAlikeArchetypeModel>("p‌​romo") but i cant use like that able to use only CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("promo") @Eyescream

Comment: i am receiving an error like this The type or namespace name 'IPropertyValueConverter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  @Eyescream

Comment: take a look at the documentation https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:uS-akIf2mwMJ:https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/extending/property-editors/value-converters+&cd=1&hl=it&ct=clnk&gl=us  (cached version because I'm getting a 404 from the official site)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat] @Eyescream
 (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146505/discussion-between-gayathri-mohan-and-eyescream).

Answer (score 1):

You should implement a Property Value Converter for your custom datatype (now you are just getting the string out!)
so that from the json you saved in the node you can get the actual type.

See https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/extending/property-editors/value-converters

Comment: i am new to umbraco i am not sure whats that converter will do i need something in Javascript we have JSON.parse like that, even i try the converter also is not working –

Comment: var obj = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<MyLookAlikeArchetypeModel>("promo");  the obj valu is comming as empty @Eyescream

Comment: does var promo = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string>("p‌​romo");  
<span>@promo</span>  print something?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're seeing is because you are using the dynamic objects, which struggle to convert objects sometimes. It thinks the promo value field is a string, so your for-each loop is basically looping through each character of the string.

As Eyescream mentioned, you could write a property value converter to make your life much easier.

Comment: i am new to umbraco i am not sure whats that converter will do i need something in Javascript we have JSON.parse like that, even i try the converter also is not working

Answer (score 0):

If the object is JSON, just derserialise it to a type and iterate over it.

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm